# Where are the pristine, untouched contents of a ~/.profile file?

Tags: system-installation, .profile, user-profile

Several files in my home directory have been disappearing. E.g. `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `authorized_keys` and now `.profile`.

Regardless of how this happened, I would like to restore the original pristine `.profile` file. If I create a new user on my system one is created. Where can I find this `.profile` contents from a fresh, untouched install?

Comment: Severa files have been disappearing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `/etc/skel/`. This is the user "skeleton" used when creating a new user. On a regular Ubuntu installation it looks like this:

```
/etc/skel
├── .bash_logout
├── .bashrc
└── .profile
```

If you add files here yourself it will be put in the home directory of newly created users. To restore the default, simply copy it from there:

```
cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/
```

Se also the `useradd` manpage on this:

> The system administrator is responsible for placing the default user files in the `/etc/skel/` directory (or any other skeleton directory specified in `/etc/default/useradd` or on the command line).
>
> `-k`, `--skel` `SKEL_DIR`
> The skeleton directory, which contains files and directories to be copied in the user's home directory, when the home directory is created by `useradd`.

While strictly not in scope for your question, but noteworthy is, also the system-wide profile file (`/etc/profile`) is evaluated on login as [Johankor mentions in his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/319211/88802).

Comment: tks gertvdijk :=]